# Estimating the the Sobolev semi-norm

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, estimation, spheres

Let $\Omega\subset \Bbb R^d$ be an open set, $u \in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ with $1\leq p<\infty $ such that  for every $\varphi\in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$  every unit vector $e\in \mathbb{S}^{d-1}$,
\begin{align}\label{eq:cont-weak-derivatve}
 \left|\int_{\Omega} u(x) \nabla \varphi (x)\cdot e ~\mathrm{d}x \right| \leq C\|\varphi\|_{L^{p'}(\Omega)}.
 \end{align}
where $1/p+1/p'=1$ and $C>0$.

Can I conclude that
\begin{align}%\label{eq:cont-weak-derivatve}
 \int_{\Omega} |\nabla u(x)|^p \mathrm{d}x \leq C^p.
 \end{align}
with $|z|= (z_1^2+\cdots+z_d^2)^{1/2}$. when I take $e= e_i$ canonical coordinates I get
\begin{align}
 \int_{\Omega} |\partial_{x_i}u(x)|^p \mathrm{d}x \leq C^p.
 \end{align}
Note that $(|z_1|^p+\cdots+|z_d|^p)^{1/p}=1$ then $|z_i|\leq 1$ so that $|z|\leq d^{1/2}$. Thu, in general $|z|^p\leq d^{p/2}(|z_1|^p+\cdots+|z_d|^p)$. Take $z=\nabla u$ then this implies

\begin{align}
  \int_{\Omega} |\nabla u(x)|^p \mathrm{d}x \leq d^{1+p/2}C^p .
 \end{align}
But I don't want the fact $d^{1+p/2}$

Comment: Are you sure about the factor $d^{2p}$? I got factor $d$ if $p\le 2$ and factor $d^{p/2}$ for $p>2$.

Comment: Assume $|z|_p=1$ then $|z_i|\leq 1$ so that $|z|\leq d^{1/2}$. Then in general $|z|^p\leq d^{p/2}|z|^p_p$....  taking $z= \nabla u$ and integrating gives the factor $d^{1+p/2}\leq d^{2p}$

Comment: This can be improved a little bit: If $|z|_p=1$ then $|z|_2\le d^{1/2-1/p}$ if $p>2$ and $|z|_2\le 1$ if $p\le 2$.